# how to load dependent assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a project Processor and it depend on other 2 projects.

When i compile project I get dll Processor.dll and other project's depend dll in Bin folder. **Processor.dll   BusinessAction.dll   and Repository.dll.**

I tried to call method from Processor.dll by initiating type **ProcessRequest** class.

Like this

```
 Assembly processorAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path + "Processor.DLL"));

        Type myType= processorAssembly.GetType("Namespace.ProcessRequest");

        myType.InvokeMember("Process", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, submitOfferType, new object[] { 12345 });
```

Process method has some logic to process and save it to database.

when i invoke procee method using InvokeMember()

i get exception **Could not load file or assembly 'Namespace.BusinessAction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I do i invoke method?

Comment: Make sure you have a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appdomain has an event which is fired if it can't find a reference:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

In the event handler you can search for the assembly manually:

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string s = @"C:\lib\" + args.Name.Remove(args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";
    return Assembly.LoadFile(s);
}
```

Comment: You saved my day buddy! ...I was looking for this for days!! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Assembly processorAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path + "Processor.DLL"));
```

this will load all supporting DLLs

Comment: This doesn't have the same effect as loading a dependent assembly. Hcb's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

@hcb has the correct answer and in 2022 it can written simply as:

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sdr, ar) => {
    string dllPath = $"C:\lib\{ar.Name.Remove(ar.Name.IndexOf(','))}.dll";
    return Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
};
```

or

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sdr, ar) => { 
    return Assembly.LoadFile($"C:\\lib\\{ar.Name.Remove(ar.Name.IndexOf(','))}.dll");
};
```

where `c:\lib\` is the path where you have the dependent dll