# how to use dependent DLL methods after load as assembly dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, appdomain

I can load Dlls dynamically. I want to use `GetSum` method after loading assemblies.

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public int GetSum(int a , int b)
        {
            try
            {
                ClassLibrary1.Class1 ctx = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
                return ctx.Sum(a, b);
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I can not use `GetSum` method.

```
public void LoadAndCall(List<byte[]> binaryList)
{
    Assembly loadedAssembly=null;

    Assembly[] assBefore = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach (byte[] binary in binaryList)
    {
        loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(binary);
        //foreach (var assemblyName in loadedAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        //    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyName);
    }
    Assembly[] assAfter = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
 //   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    object[] tt = { 3, 6 };
    Type type = loadedAssembly.GetType("ClassLibrary2.Class1");
    object loaded = loadedAssembly.CreateInstance("ClassLibrary2.Class1", true, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { }, null, null);
   // object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);



    ObjectCreateMethod inv = new ObjectCreateMethod(type); //Specify Type
    Object obj = inv.CreateInstance();

    MethodInfo minfo = type.GetMethod("GetSum", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance);
    int x = (int)minfo.Invoke(obj, new Object[] { 3, 6 });
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

how to use `GetSum` method? classlib2 depends on classlib1 library. They are loaded dynamically Appdomain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use loaded DLLS assembly' methods which is referenced to another assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663920/how-to-use-loaded-dlls-assembly-methods-which-is-referenced-to-another-assembly)